# Shortening critical sections in thread-safe (unbalanced) Binary Tree

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, mutex

I'm implementing a set of thread-safe functions that update and search an unbalanced binary tree with Pthreads (see [The Linux Programming Interface](https://www.nostarch.com/tlpi): Exercise [30.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=2SAQAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=TLPI%20exercise%2030.2&pg=PA653#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

It's easy to implement a working tree that locks the entire body of functions like `add` or `delete`, but I believe it possible to implement an unbalanced binary (search) tree with a fine-grained locking strategy.

I've tried to 'port' a variety of hand-over-hand locking schemes from other data structures described in '[The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916)' but each requires that I transform the tree into a different primitive data structure (I'd like this to *use* an unbalanced binary tree as it's primitive data type, not just provide the same interface)

For clarity, here is the data structure used to represent the nodes of this tree.

```
typedef struct bt_node {
    Key key;
    int value;
    struct bt_node *left;
    struct bt_node *right;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} bt_node;
```

(I also maintain a `bt_root` structure for bookkeeping purposes, which you may see in some functions below)

The `add` function is essentially single-threaded as I end up locking the root node almost at the beginning of `add` and unlocking it after it's work is complete. Is it possible to do better here? (`lock` and `unlock` are wrappers around [`pthread_mutex_lock`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) and [`pthread_mutex_unlock`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock) for the structure above)

```
// This function is responsible for finding the last node that is going to be the parent of whichever node we are inserting.
bt_node *closest_leaf(bt_node *root, Key key) {
    bt_node *current = root;
    bt_node *prev = NULL;
    while (current != NULL) {
        prev = current;
        if      (key < current->key)  current = current->left;
        else if (key > current->key)  current = current->right;
        else  {
            prev = current;
            break;
        }
    }

    return prev;
}

int add(bt_root *root_tree, Key key, int value) {
    bt_node *new_node = create_node(key, value);
    bt_node *current = root_tree->root;

    // this root creation code is not and need not be thread-safe.
    if (current == NULL) {
        root_tree->root = new_node;
        root_tree->node_count = 1;
        return 1;
    }

    lock(current);
    // just locking `leaf` & `current` inside closest_leaf is incorrect
    bt_node *leaf = closest_leaf(current, key);
    if (key < leaf->key) {
        leaf->left = new_node;
        ++root_tree->node_count;
    }
    else if (key > leaf->key) {
        leaf->right = new_node;
        ++root_tree->node_count;
    } else {
        free(new_node);
    }
    unlock(current);


    return 1;
}
```

Deletion shares this problem: successful deletion schemes effectively lock the entire tree. The code shown below omits mutex acquisition and relinquishment code (but the concept is the same as above).

```
// splice is the function responsible for actually removing a node from the tree
void splice(bt_node *node, bt_node *parent) {
    // if it's a leaf, destroy it.
    if (!node->left && !node->right) {
             replace_parent(parent, node, NULL);

    // if it has one child, have them be adopted by their grandparent
    } else if (node->left && !node->right) {
            replace_parent(parent, node, node->left);
    } else if (node->right && !node->left) {
            replace_parent(parent, node, node->right);

    /* if it has two children, take the smallest value of the right tree and
       replace the node with that one. */
    } else if (node->right && node->left) {
        // find the smallest element of the right tree
        bt_node *smallest_parent = node;
        bt_node *smallest = node->right;
        while (smallest->left) {
            smallest_parent = smallest;
            // left is the smaller side
            smallest = smallest->left;
        }

        // "swap" the smallest.
        node->key = smallest->key;
        node->value = smallest->value;

        // unsure if this is correct -- seems to be only sensible thing to do
        smallest_parent->left = smallest->right;
        free(smallest);
    }
}

// search the tree depth-first for the node to remove
int delete_dfs(bt_node *node, bt_node *parent, Key key) {
    if (node == NULL) return 0;
    Key node_key = node->key;

    // we've found the key, let's actually splice it out of the tree
    if (node_key == key) {
        splice(node, parent);
        return 1;
    }

    // otherwise we should search (depth first).
    if (key < node_key) {
        return delete_dfs(node->left, node, key);
    } else if (key > node_key) {
        return delete_dfs(node->right, node, key);
    }

    return 0;
}

void delete(bt_root *root_tree, Key key) {
    if (delete_dfs(root_tree->root, NULL, key)) root_tree->node_count--;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement a hand-over-hand locking scheme for your insert function, you need to do it within the `closest_leaf()` function

```
// This function is responsible for finding the last node that is going to be the parent of whichever node we are inserting.

// post-condition: returned node is locked
bt_node *closest_leaf(bt_node *root, Key key) {
    bt_node *current = root;
    bt_node *prev = NULL;
    while (current != NULL) {
        lock(current);
        if (prev)
            unlock(prev);
        prev = current;
        if      (key < current->key)  current = current->left;
        else if (key > current->key)  current = current->right;
        else
            break;
    }

    return prev;
}
```

(As we descend down the tree, we lock each node before examining it, and we unlock it only after we lock the next node we're going to examine).  This returns with the node locked, so we can then modify it in the `add()` function:

```
int add(bt_root *root_tree, Key key, int value)
{
    bt_node *new_node = create_node(key, value);
    bt_node *current = root_tree->root;

    // this root creation code is not and need not be thread-safe.
    if (current == NULL) {
        root_tree->root = new_node;
        root_tree->node_count = 1;
        return 1;
    }

    bt_node *leaf = closest_leaf(current, key);
    if (key < leaf->key) {
        leaf->left = new_node;
        ++root_tree->node_count;
    }
    else if (key > leaf->key) {
        leaf->right = new_node;
        ++root_tree->node_count;
    } else {
        free(new_node);
    }
    unlock(leaf);

    return 1;
}
```

Deletion is a little more complex.  Firstly, we need to fix a bug in your `splice()` function - consider what happens if `smallest_parent == node` after the `while()` loop (ie, the loop executed zero times): it will overwrite `node->left` when it should be overwriting `node->right`.  The easiest way to fix this is with a pointer-to-a-pointer that points at the parent field we want to update, rather than a pointer to the parent itself.

At the same time, `splice()` can be simplified by observing that the modification it does to `parent` is only ever to change the pointer field in parent that points at `node` - so we can just take a single argument that's a pointer to that pointer field.  This means we don't need the `replace_parent()` function anymore either.  The simplified `splice()`, *without* locking, looks like:

```
// splice is the function responsible for actually removing a node from the tree
void splice(bt_node **node_ptr) {
    bt_node *node = *node_ptr;
    // if it has one or zero child nodes, have them be adopted by their grandparent
    if (!node->left) {
        *node_ptr = node->right;
        free(node);
    }
    else if (!node->right) {
        *node_ptr = node->left;
        free(node);
    }
    /* if it has two children, take the smallest value of the right tree and
       replace the node with that one. */
    else {
        // find the smallest element of the right tree
        bt_node **smallest_ptr = &node->right;
        bt_node *smallest = *smallest_ptr;

        while (smallest->left) {
            smallest_ptr = &smallest->left;
            smallest = *smallest_ptr;
        }

        // "swap" the smallest.
        node->key = smallest->key;
        node->value = smallest->value;
        *smallest_ptr = smallest->right;
        free(smallest);
    }
}
```

To add the locking, we're going to require that `splice()` is called with both the parent node and the child node to be deleted locked.  In the simple splice cases then, we just need to unlock the child node before freeing it. In the complex case we need to do our hand-over-hand locking again as we find the next-smallest node to swap in:

```
// splice is the function responsible for actually removing a node from the tree
// pre-condition: node **node_ptr and its parent (containing the pointer *node_ptr) are both locked
void splice(bt_node **node_ptr) {
    bt_node *node = *node_ptr;
    // if it has one or zero child nodes, have them be adopted by their grandparent
    if (!node->left) {
        *node_ptr = node->right;
        unlock(node);
        free(node);
    }
    else if (!node->right) {
        *node_ptr = node->left;
        unlock(node);
        free(node);
    }
    /* if it has two children, take the smallest value of the right tree and
       replace the node with that one. */
    else {
        // find the smallest element of the right tree
        bt_node **smallest_ptr = &node->right;
        bt_node *smallest = *smallest_ptr;

        lock(smallest);
        while (smallest->left) {
            smallest_ptr = &smallest->left;
            lock(*smallest_ptr);
            unlock(smallest);
            smallest = *smallest_ptr;
        }

        // "swap" the smallest.
        node->key = smallest->key;
        node->value = smallest->value;
        *smallest_ptr = smallest->right;
        unlock(node);
        unlock(smallest);
        free(smallest);
    }
}
```

Note that in this last part of the deletion where we find the next-smallest node, we don't need to keep the parent node of 'smallest' locked even though we modify it.  The reason is that we keep 'node' locked the whole time, so after we've done the hand-over-hand locking down to 'smallest' we have exclusive access to all the nodes in that chain.

To make this hand-over-hand deletion work, it's easiest to replace the recursive deletion with the iterative version.  (You also need to supply a function to lock the root of the tree, because if the root node has less than two child nodes and is deleted, the pointer in the root will be updated, so this needs mutual exclusion):

```
void delete(bt_root *root_tree, Key key)
{
    bt_node *node;
    bt_node *prev = NULL;
    bt_node **node_ptr = &root_tree->root;
    int deleted = 0;

    lock_root(root_tree);
    while ((node = *node_ptr) != NULL)
    {
        lock(node);
        if (key == node->key)
        {
            splice(node_ptr);
            deleted = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (prev)
                unlock(prev);
            else
                unlock_root(root_tree);
            prev = node;
            if (key < node->key)
                node_ptr = &node->left;
            else
                node_ptr = &node->right;
        }
    }

    if (prev) {
        unlock(prev);
        if (deleted) {
            lock_root(root_tree);
            root_tree->node_count--;
            unlock_root(root_tree);
        }           
    } else {
        if (deleted) {
            root_tree->node_count--;
        }
        unlock_root(root_tree);
    }
}
```

You also need to use this `lock_root()` / `unlock_root()` pair when traversing the tree for the add function as well, to ensure you don't traverse into a root node that's about to be freed by a concurrent deletion.  This requires updating `closest_leaf()` to take a `bt_root *` rather than `bt_node *` argument, but also makes the first insertion into the tree thread-safe as well:

```
// This function is responsible for finding the last node that is going to be the parent of whichever node we are inserting.
// post-condition: returned node is locked, or tree is locked if NULL is returned
bt_node *closest_leaf(bt_root *tree, Key key)
{
    bt_node *current;
    bt_node *prev = NULL;

    lock_root(tree);
    current = tree->root;
    while (current != NULL) {
        lock(current);
        if (prev)
            unlock(prev);
        else
            unlock_root(tree);
        prev = current;
        if      (key < current->key)  current = current->left;
        else if (key > current->key)  current = current->right;
        else
            break;
    }

    return prev;
}

int add(bt_root *root_tree, Key key, int value)
{
    bt_node *new_node = create_node(key, value);
    bt_node *leaf = closest_leaf(root_tree, key);

    /* NULL returned by closest_leaf() means new node is the root */
    if (leaf == NULL) {
        root_tree->root = new_node;
        root_tree->node_count = 1;
        unlock_root(root_tree);
        return 1;
    }

    if (key == leaf->key) {
        free(new_node);
        unlock(leaf);
    } else {    
        if (key < leaf->key) {
            leaf->left = new_node;
        }
        else {
            leaf->right = new_node;
        }
        unlock(leaf);

        lock_root(root_tree);
        ++root_tree->node_count;
        unlock_root(root_tree);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Note the added complication and locking required to keep the `node_count` up-to-date - you should reconsider whether it's worth having.

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin: I have updated this answer - it turns out that you can't avoid protecting the updates to the root node with a lock in the `bt_root`, because a deletion on the root node when it only has one (or zero) child nodes will cause the pointer in the `bt_root` to be updated and that could race with a concurrent `add` operation.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm implementing a set of thread-safe functions that update and search
>   an unbalanced binary tree with Pthreads (see The Linux Programming
>   Interface: Exercise 30.2).
>
> It's easy to implement a 'functional' tree that simply locks the
>   entire body of functions like add or delete, but I believe it possible
>   to implement an unbalanced binary (search) tree with a locking
>   strategy that allows for almost all the work to be parallelized by
>   minimizing time spent in a critical section.

Yes and no.  If two or more threads are to access the same shared data, and at least one of them modifies it, then both threads' accesses must be protected by some form of synchronization.  Since you cannot, in general, predict in advance which nodes may be modified, all accesses need to be synchronized.  On the other hand, the scope of the protected region can vary dynamically.  Tree search, addition, and deletion algorithms for an unbalanced tree can narrow the scope of needed synchronization as they go, as in principle they only need to protect a subtree.  Another thread could reasonably operate at the same time on a separate subtree.

Before you get excited about that, however, be aware that changing the synchronization scope is going to require a mutex lock and unlock (or *vise versa*, depending on your approach), and these are not cheap.  You might find, in fact, that all the mutex locking and unlocking eats up most or all of the gains from parallelizing operations.

However, if you anticipate that searches will be the predominant operation on your tree, with additions and deletions being comparatively rare, then you could consider implementing a read/write lock.  The idea there is that you permit any number of threads to search the tree at the same time, but a thread that wants to modify it must be granted exclusive access to the whole tree before it can do so.

Comment: Initially, I locked subtrees as you suggest, a problem arose where `closest_leaf` is executed by more than one thread and the results of one overwrites the other (even if the `node` being modified is locked). I definitely agree with your 'big picture' analysis, but in this case the Tree need not consider 'predominant operations' or other practical concerns. I am *fairly* sure that it is possible to implement `add` & `delete` without locking more than the node currently being modified (existing literature suggests it's possible to implement them entirely without mutexes).

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin, something is *dreadfully* wrong if a tree **search** modifies the tree.  If, while a search has a given subtree locked, some other operation is able to modify any node in it, then it's your locking implementation that's wrong.  The general approach of locking subtrees is sound.

Comment: I think if you look at the code you'll see what I mean - A BST needs to find *where* to insert (search) prior to actually inserting. 

I agree that locking sub-trees *is* sound (indeed, the whole question is predicated on this!) - the problem is that the obvious strategy yields some problems.

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin, I'm saying that if you had correctly locked (the correct) subtrees as I suggest, then you would not have had the misbehavior you describe.  That you did experience misbehavior probably means that the scope of your locking was too narrow, or that your mechanism for narrowing the scope was unsafe.  In particular, you must not unlock the current node before locking the child you intend to traverse next.  For deletion, you must in fact keep the subtree rooted at the current node's parent locked, because splicing out a node requires modifying that node's parent.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have been ambiguous -- yes you are absolutely correct. I am not disputing that if I locked the correct sub-trees, this code would work. I would like assistance from someone with a mature understanding of the topic to offer some guidance on what I might be overlooking. I do appreciate your time here and I can understand that you can't just spend a bunch of precious time on a stranger's exercise code, but to be clear my problem in this case is that I have tried a variety of subtree locking strategies and they are all broken in subtle ways.